# Where to start debugging "ResourceNotFoundException" while using AWS SDK Javascript v3 for Alexa skill building

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am building an Alexa hosted skill using node.js, and I would like to include user specific data from a DynamoDB table in my personal AWS account. I have set up a Cognito Identity pool with access permission for the DynamoDB table and managed to retrieve credentials using the AWS SDK for Javascript (v3), but when I try to use the DynamoDB client to access the table I get a "resource not found" exception.

I can't even figure out how to access the request object to try and diagnose the problem! It seems like the original request would be returned as part of the response if it was successful, but the error object only includes a request ID string which doesn't tell me anything. If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great, but I can probably work it out if I could just get some pointers on how to get more information to start debugging! As I am not in North America it seems that the local debugging kit isn't available to me, so all I have to work with is the the Alexa developer console code editor/simulator with the lambda CloudLogs.

All ideas much appreciated, thanks!

**Alexa Skill Code**

```
const NewSessionRequestInterceptor = {
    async process(handlerInput) {
    if(isNewSession(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)){
        const cognitoIdentityClient = new CognitoIdentityClient({region: "eu-west-1"});
        const amazonAccessToken = getAccountLinkingAccessToken(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const cgGetIdCommand = new GetIdCommand({
            IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            Logins:{'www.amazon.com':amazonAccessToken}
        });
        const cgIdStr = await cognitoIdentityClient.send(cgGetIdCommand);
        const cgGetCredentialsCommand = new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({
            IdentityId:cgIdStr.IdentityId, 
            Logins:{'www.amazon.com':amazonAccessToken}
        });
        const cgCredentials = await cognitoIdentityClient.send(cgGetCredentialsCommand);
        const DynamoDBClientConfig = Object.assign(
            {identityId:cgIdStr.IdentityId, region:"eu-west-1"}, cgCredentials.Credentials
        );
        const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient(DynamoDBClientConfig);
        const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient);
        const command = new GetCommand({
            TableName:"MySkillData", 
            Key:{'UserId':cgIdStr.IdentityId, 'ItemKey':"Settings"}, 
            ConsistentRead:true
        })
        var Response;
        try{
            Response = await ddbDocClient.send(command);
        }catch(err){Response = err}
        handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes({cgCredentials, Response});
    }}}
```

**Request Error/Credentials (saved to session attributes and returned in skill response)**

```
"sessionAttributes": {
    "Response": {
        "name": "ResourceNotFoundException",
        "$fault": "client",
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "requestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        }
    },
    "cgCredentials": {
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "requestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "Credentials": {
            "AccessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "Expiration": "2021-04-20T14:20:04.000Z",
            "SecretKey": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "SessionToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "IdentityId": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}}
```

**Cognito Identity Pool Authorised Role Permissions Policy**

```
{    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/"MySkillData"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]}}}]}
```

**Cognito Identity Pool Authorised Role Trust Relationships Policy**

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'"
          },
          "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"}}}]}
```

Comment: Local debugging was rolled out outside NA. Use the ASK Toolkit for VS Code. But you can also `console.log()` any debug info you want and it will be recorded to the free CloudWatch logs with Alexa Hosted. Use the 'CloudWatch' icon in the Code tab to access it,

Comment: Thanks, good to know! I did actually try using the VS Code editor previously and thought it worked okay, but when I tried adding the AWS packages I got a lot of errors and I thought it might be because the debugger wasn't intended for my region, so I gave up! I know how to see the CloudWatch logs, but how can I get the finalised request object to pass to the console log?

Comment: Use console.dir() to log out a surface level reflection of an object. There's also a util package in Node. console.log(util.inspect(object)) will dive even deeper, depending on the params you set.

Comment: But where do I find the object? I have the client and the command, and then I use
client.send(command) and it builds the object and sends it, but I don't know how to access the object after it is built and before it is sent. If the request is successful then a copy of the request is returned with the response, but you don't get to see the request if it returns an error. I'm sure this must be a simple thing to do but I can't work it out.